# Port foward THOMSON DWG874B

Tags: router, port-forwarding, port

I've been trying to follow several tutorials, with no success.

Here are some screenshots:

http://share.pho.to/AVIuw

Looks like some people are facing same issue. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you confirm that your own Linux Host is not preventing access to that port? Maybe the request did reach your linux host, but your linux host actively rejecting it?

Comment: Should i try to do this? : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73767/how-to-check-whether-firewall-opened-for-a-port-but-not-listening-on-the-port

Comment: Something along that line yes. But the simplest test would be (since you are the admin of your own linux host): Is the service that should be accepting connection on that port is running? And is there a way you can check locally that it is running? (say another PC connecting to 192.168.0.11:27015 and your program is connected fine). Once you got that confirmed, then try checking using external IP (which should get port-forwarded to your 192.168.0.11)

Comment: On a different notebook, at the same network, i'm able to connect both from local IP and from external IP.

Comment: Any chance your ISP is blocking it?

Comment: I think not. I will receive a visit from my ISP technician tomorrow, and i hope he can fix this. Any other issues it could be related?

Comment: On the same network - sometimes your router could be smart enough to know it is meant to go local, so it just redirect it locally. If you got your phone handy, you can use it as an access point, and connect your notebook to it (so it will be considered a fully external access) and then connect in (using your external IP). If its blocked, then most likely your ISP is blocking certain ports.

Comment: Unfortunately my phone has no access to internet. I will try some more debugging steps, and will come back later with results.